# How to submit form using JQuery and Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am having difficulty understanding why my form submits successful when i disable the ajax function. When i enable ajax on my input form. Input values i fill are not submitted. I used chrome developer tools to check the FormData being submitted. I realized nothing was being submit.
Hence i get an error asking me to fill those fields.

Controller

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/basicAjax.json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addCertJson(@Valid @ModelAttribute CertificateProgramme certificate, BindingResult result, Principal principal) {
        User user = (User) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal();
        certificate.setUser(user);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> errors = result.getAllErrors().stream()
                    .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            certificateService.save(certificate);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        }
    }
```

JS Script

```
var $form = $('.editCert');
var formData = $form.serialize();
var url = $form.attr('action');
var storage = {};
$.each($('.editCert').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    storage[field.name] = field.value;
});

$form.on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(url,{
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: storage,
            type: "POST",
        }).done(function(response){
           if(response.status === 'SUCCESS'){
                 console.log('I am Okay' + response);
                  }else{
                  console.log('Holly Molly');
                   }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          var errorInfo="";
          for(i =0 ; i <jqXHR.responseJSON.length ; i++){
                           errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + jqXHR.responseJSON[i];
                       }
                    var $myerror =  $form.find('.flash').addClass(' failure');
                        $myerror.html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
           });
    });
```

Form

```
<form  method="post" th:object="${certificate}"
      th:action="@{${action1}}" class="form-inline inline new-item editCert">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <div th:replace="common/layout :: flash"></div>
    <div class="flash"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend th:text="${heading}"> Personal Information</legend>
        <div class="row" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('fullName')}? 'error' : ''">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{fullName}"
                   placeholder="Full Name example Jane Doe"/>
            <div class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('fullName')}" th:errors="*{fullName}"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}? 'error' : ''">
            <select th:field="*{gender}" class="form-control input-lg ">
                <option value="">[Select Gender]</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <div class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}" th:errors="*{gender}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}? 'error' : ''">
            <input th:type="date" data-value="20/04/2015" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" th:field="*{date}"
                   placeholder="Date Of Birth"/>
            <div class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}" th:errors="*{date}"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you enable ajax, form data is probably sent in json format. When you disable ajax, the data is sent in formdata format, you should adapt your controller to your need. In your Jquery, it seems like you are stopping the submit using  e.preventDefault();, and sending the data as AJAX, why would you do that?

Comment: @zakariaamine I am preventing the default function because, i am loading that form into a div. Hence i can use the jQuery $.post or $,Jquery functionality to submit the form async. If i don't do that i wouldn't  get the functionality i want. In any case that is not why the form is not submitting to the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, Moved the form iteration into the submit $.ajax submit function

```
$form.on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        storage[field.name] = field.value;
    });
   console.log(storage);
    $.ajax(url,{
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: storage,
            type: "POST",
        }).done(function(response){
                 console.log('I am Okay' + response);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);
          if(jqXHR.status === 400){
          var errorInfo="";
          for(i =0 ; i <jqXHR.responseJSON.length ; i++){
                           errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + jqXHR.responseJSON[i];
                       }
                    var $myerror =  $form.find('.flash').addClass(' failure');
                        $myerror.html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
            }
           });
    });
```